# change a sequence of background images as spritesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have conversation screen to be developed i have planned to change the background images for every millisecond so that it looks like a animation. I tried using jquery settimeout and setinterval but both the ways stack of images changing in small interval hangs the browser, any ideas of how to accomplish my task.

```
function change_background(new_image_source) { 
    var myimage = $( '#spriteanim' );
    myimage.attr('src','style/images/Sprites/Screen1/'+new_image_source+'.png');
    console.log(myimage.attr('src'));
    timer = setTimeout( function () {
        new_image_source = new_image_source+1;
        change_background(new_image_source);
    }, 50);

    if(new_image_source>=10899){
        change_background(new_image_source);
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the src attribute will never work as you want. That's because the browser needs time to load the image. Even it is cached it is still too slow for animating. I'll suggest to combine your images into sprite and change the *background-position*. You can even do that with pure css transition.

For example -> http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/uzZqg/

HTML

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

CSS

```
.image {
    background: url('...');
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: all 4000ms;
    -webkit-transition: all 4000ms;
}
.image:hover {
    background-position: -500px 0;
}
```

You can even use [keyframes](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp).

Here is how you can preload your images http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/DfWJm/1/

HTML

```
<div id="preloader"></div>
```

JS

```
var images = [
'http://www.australia.com/contentimages/about-landscapes-nature.jpg',
'http://www.australia.com/contentimages/about-landscapes-nature.jpg',
'http://www.australia.com/contentimages/about-landscapes-nature.jpg',
'http://www.australia.com/contentimages/about-landscapes-nature.jpg',
'http://www.australia.com/contentimages/about-landscapes-nature.jpg',
'http://www.australia.com/contentimages/about-landscapes-nature.jpg'    
];

var preloader = document.getElementById("preloader");
var preloadImages = function(callback) {
    if(images.length == 0) {
        callback();
        return;
    }
    var image = images.shift();
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.setAttribute("src", image);
    preloader.appendChild(img); 
    img.addEventListener("load", function() {
        console.log("image loaded");
        preloadImages(callback);
    });    
}

preloadImages(function() {
    // your animation starts here
    alert("Images loaded");
});
```

Of course you may hide the *#preloader* div with *display: none*;

Comment: Every image is of 1024*768 and no of images are about 800 its not possible create a sprite and perform animation on it believe.

Comment: Is it possible to show some of the images? Do you have to animate the whole image?

Comment: I need to show all of them that's wat makes it a conversation...which i am trying to accomplish..

Comment: The question was to give us a better idea what the images are all about. I.e. how they look, but anyway. It looks like, as the others suggested, you should add them to the DOM first. So, they could be cached. After that try to replace them one after another. However if you are going to show the whole 1024x768 that's very very big area to reflow.

Comment: K if i load all of them before animation starts and showing them one by one (show&hide) would it be easy...

Comment: Let me give you an example how this could be accomplish.

Comment: Just added an example of preloading.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout http://spritely.net/

It'll handle the details of animating a spritesheet. Let's you set FPS and control playback.

Comment: Thanks will but i am not animating sprites here but need to change background images in an interval that look like an animation..

Answer (score 0):

I think 'every millisecond' is a bit too fast.
Image load takes some time. I think, you should load all the images once, before starting the animation. It will take some time, since number of images you are using seems to be **10899**. And just hide all but one every few milliseconds. 'Few milliseconds', instead of 'every millisecond', should do your job.

UPDATE:
Name your images `spriteanim0`, `spriteanim1`... like this. After all the images have been loaded, and all have been assigned `display: none`, call this js function:

```
    var new_image_source1;
    function change_background(prev_image_source, new_image_source) {
        document.getElementById('spriteanim' + prev_image_source).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('spriteanim' + new_image_source).style.display = 'block';
        if (new_image_source >= 10899)
            new_image_source1 = 0;
        else
            new_image_source1 = new_image_source + 1;
        window.setTimeout(
            function () {
                change_background(new_image_source, new_image_source1);
            },
            50);
    }
```

You can try this and change the `setTimeout` interval value accordingly, as needed.